# Why doesn't the collection get populated with OPEN cursor BULK COLLECT .. LIMIT

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to populate a collection with a bulk collect .. limit clause. Code works if i use the normal BULK COLLECT without limit. But with the BULK COLLECT .. LIMIT loop, the collection is not getting populated. Also I dont understand why the collectionname.COUNT = 0 when there are no more values to be fetched.

Code is below:

```
DECLARE
   c_limit PLS_INTEGER := 5;

   CURSOR employees_cur
   IS
      SELECT employee_id
        FROM employees;

   TYPE employee_ids_t IS TABLE OF 
      employees.employee_id%TYPE;

   l_employee_ids   employee_ids_t;
BEGIN
   OPEN employees_cur;

   LOOP
      FETCH employees_cur
      BULK COLLECT INTO l_employee_ids
      LIMIT c_limit;

   dbms_output.put_line ('after bulk collect count '||l_employee_ids.COUNT);
   dbms_output.put_line ('after bulk collect first '||l_employee_ids.FIRST);
   dbms_output.put_line ('after bulk collect last '||l_employee_ids.LAST);

      EXIT WHEN l_employee_ids.COUNT = 0;

   END LOOP;

   CLOSE employees_cur;

    dbms_output.put_line ('Outside loop: ');
   dbms_output.put_line ('after bulk collect count '||l_employee_ids.COUNT);
   dbms_output.put_line ('after bulk collect first '||l_employee_ids.FIRST);
   dbms_output.put_line ('after bulk collect last '||l_employee_ids.LAST);
EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
   dbms_output.put_line ('Error: '||SQLERRM);
END;
```

There is no exception raised. Outside the loop collection.COUNT is showing 0 and FIRST and LAST are NULL. 
I dont understand what went wrong. The code is almost verbatim (except for the put_lines) from an Oracle blog example. 
https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/bulk-processing-with-bulk-collect-and-forall

(Code Listing 6: Fetching up to the number of rows specified)

I am on 12.1 Oracle

Inside the loop for each iteration, COUNT = LIMIT value, and FIRST is 1 and LAST =COUNT are the values printed.

Comment: `l_employee_ids.COUNT` equals 0 (zero) after the loop because that is your exit condition. As long as `COUNT` is not zero, you stay in the loop. What did you expect it to be?

Comment: @Abra I used it as it was in the example. I dont understand why it is 0. IF we are putting5 elements into the collection in each loop, shouldn't the collection count go like 5,10,15 etc?

Comment: A quote from the article you linked to: _no matter how many rows I need to fetch, my session will never consume more memory than that required for those 100 rows_ In other words, `l_employee_ids` will ___never___ contain more than 5 rows according to the code you posted in your question. In each loop iteration, `l_employee_ids` is emptied and filled again.

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting the data to be added to the collection during each loop.For example after second loop you want the data in the collection to be 10.But limit doesn't work that way you have to make use of the collection inside the loop itself because at each iteration the collection almost has 5 elements which is the LIMIT of the collection

Comment: Thanks! This is the epiphany i was looking for